# How can I correctly send an envelope using DocuSign that includes two copies of the document, to two recipients, one for each to sign?

Tags: api, docusignapi

I'm using the DocuSign.eSign package (DocuSign.eSign.dll v2.1.10) and encountering a problem in a specific scenario. In this instance, I'm trying to send an envelope to two signers, with two copies of the same document in it, one for each of them to sign. I've been told that redesign of the form is not an option, so when we need both partners in a couple to sign the form, they each must sign their own copy of the same form.

I've confirmed that the envelope contains 2 documents (DocumentID 1, DocumentID 2) and two signers, and each signer has just 1 SignHereTab with the correct corresponding DocumentID defined.

However, when the signers receive the envelope, each signer has SignHereTabs on each of the two documents. When the envelope is completed, there are overlapping signatures for both people on both documents.

I've tried dynamically naming the documents as well, so the names will be unique as are the ID's, with no luck. I must be missing something obvious. How can I correct so that signer A signs only DocumentID 1, and signer B signs only DocumentID 2, when they are both the "same" document?

ADDED: This is only happening when the tabs are defined as positioned by anchors rather than coordinates. It seems to be detecting the anchor text on both documents, although the SignHereTab is defined as belonging only to the specified document.

```
{
  "documents": [
    {
      "documentBase64": "...",
      "documentId": "1",
      "fileExtension": "doc",
      "name": "Limitation Of Liability"
    },
    {
      "documentBase64": "...",
      "documentId": "2",
      "fileExtension": "doc",
      "name": "Limitation Of Liability"
    }
  ],
  "recipients": {
    "signers": [
      {
        "accessCode": "***",
        "email": "client1@test.com",
        "name": "Client One",
        "recipientId": "1",
        "routingOrder": "1",
        "tabs": {
          "checkboxTabs": [],
          "dateSignedTabs": [],
          "initialHereTabs": [],
          "numberTabs": [],
          "radioGroupTabs": [],
          "signerAttachmentTabs": [],
          "signHereTabs": [
            {
              "anchorString": "Client Signature",
              "anchorXOffset": "0",
              "anchorYOffset": "-20",
              "documentId": "1",
              "name": "Signature",
              "recipientId": "client1@test.com",
              "scaleValue": "1",
              "tabId": "1",
              "tabLabel": "1"
            }
          ],
          "textTabs": []
        }
      },
      {
        "accessCode": "***",
        "email": "client2@test.com",
        "name": "Client Two",
        "recipientId": "2",
        "routingOrder": "2",
        "tabs": {
          "checkboxTabs": [],
          "dateSignedTabs": [],
          "initialHereTabs": [],
          "numberTabs": [],
          "radioGroupTabs": [],
          "signerAttachmentTabs": [],
          "signHereTabs": [
            {
              "anchorString": "Client Signature",
              "anchorXOffset": "0",
              "anchorYOffset": "-20",
              "documentId": "2",
              "name": "Signature",
              "recipientId": "client2@test.com",
              "scaleValue": "1",
              "tabId": "2",
              "tabLabel": "2"
            }
          ],
          "textTabs": []
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": "sent"
}
```

[showing rendered duplicated tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5Bme.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a setting at an account level for your DS Account for anchor String population scope, by default it is `Envelope` scope. So if same anchor string is present on both the documents in the envelope then DocuSign will apply tabs for each signer on each document. To fix this, you need to ask DocuSign Support or your DocuSign's Account Manager to change the scope to Document instead of Envelope from DocuSign's backend Internal Admin tool.

Once scope is set to `Document` then you can add documentId alongwith the anchorString for each String, and it will apply tab for that specific signer only.

Also please note, backend Internal Admin will show the Anchor Population scope as `Document` (which is a UI bug) but it is actually Envelope. So ask DS person who you are working with to toggle that scope twice, first to `Envelope` and then back to `Document` scope.

Comment: I have a similar use case where I am sending the same document to two signers. The problem I am facing here is I have two anchor strings for each signers but both the SignHereTabs are appearing for both signers. Please help me with it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your code so I don't know how you are placing the tags. If you are using X/Y coordinates, then you should make sure they are not overlapping by moving it.
If you are using anchorString, then perhaps you used the same string for both tags for both recipients? that would explain why they would overlap

EDIT: saw your edit about using an anchor. You should probably check where these text is in the original document. If you cannot modify the original document you can use pixels to move the tags away from the string.

(anchor tag allows you to use an offset from the text so you can move them around)

EDIT2: Since you now added you code I think the issue is the tabLabel is the same for both tabs.
The tabs should have unique labels and that would resolve the issue.

Comment: I'm sorry I may not have explained well. Person 1 should sign only document 1 and person 2 should sign only document 2, and the tags are defined as belonging to document 1 and document 2 correctly. But when the envelope is delivered, tag 1 appears on both document 1 and 2, and tag 2 appears on both document 1 and 2. I've suggested modifying the original document and been met with resistance.

Comment: we need to see your code. You can specify the documentId for the tag and it should only show for that document if done correctly.

Comment: Thank you, I've added the applicable EnvelopeDefinition output to my post.

Comment: Aha! I think your issue is the tabLabel. It appears both tabs have the exact same label, is that right? can you try to have different labels and see if that fixes it?

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't have any effect. I did want to emphasize that this happens only when doing "anchor" tabs. When the tabs are defined by coordinates, they each appear only on the corresponding document. When they're defined by anchors, it puts both on both.

Comment: can you use different anchorText for the different recipients?

Comment: In a word, no. The anchor text is on the document, which is the same document for each recipient. Are you saying that DocuSign searches all documents in an envelope for the AnchorText from the tabs on ANY document in the envelope, regardless of the defined IDs? If that's the case, that's a major design flaw. An envelope could certainly contain two or more different documents that anchor with the same text (aka "Sign here").

Comment: are both tabs on the same page? can you add pageNumber that is different for ecah?

Comment: Tab 1 is on document 1 which is a 1 page document. Tab 2 is on document 2 which is a 1 page document.

Comment: can you try to add tabId values for each tab that are different?

Comment: That also had no impact. I'll update the code sample to reflect this was tried.

Comment: just to be 100% sure, can you make the tabLabel and tabId "1" and "2" so they're completely different? I'm trying things here, sorry about that, as I'm not sure what the problem

Comment: Thank you for your help and suggestions! I've updated tabLabel and tabId "1" and "2", and it had the same result. I'll update the code sample once more. I appreciate it.

Comment: what URL do you use with the JSON above?

Comment: POST /v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/{documentId}/tabs or POST /v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients/{recipientId}/tabs

Comment: note one is under recipients and one is under documents. did you try both?

Comment: I am using the EnvelopesApi.CreateEnvelope which uses the DocuSign.eSign.Model.EnvelopeDefinition, I have version 2.1.10.0

Comment: so, I would try to create the envelope first, and add the tabs on a separate call